# Entangled qubits measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

I have two entangled qubits. I measure one of the qubits and get a 1. Am I correct in saying that the second qubit instantaneously collapsed to a correlated state, even before I measured it? Or does the second qubit only collapse to a correlated state when I measured it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the example from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement):

> For example, the following is an entangled state:
>
> $${\displaystyle {\tfrac {1}{\sqrt {2}}}\left(|0\rangle _{A} \otimes
> >  |1 \rangle _{B}-|1\rangle _{A} \otimes |0 \rangle _{B}\right).} $$.
>   Now suppose Alice is an observer for system A, and Bob is an observer
>   for system B. If in the entangled state given above Alice makes a
>   measurement in the ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle \{|0\rangle ,|1\rangle
> > \}} \scriptstyle \{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\}$ eigenbasis of A, there are
>   two possible outcomes, occurring with equal probability:
>
> Alice measures 0, and the state of the system collapses to
>   ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle |0\rangle _{A}|1\rangle _{B}}$
>
> Alice measures 1, and the state of the system collapses to
>   ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle |1\rangle _{A}|0\rangle _{B}}.$

So the state instantaneously collapses.

> If the former occurs, then any subsequent measurement performed by
>   Bob, in the same basis, will always return 1. If the latter occurs,
>   (Alice measures 1) then Bob's measurement will return 0 with
>   certainty. Thus, system B has been altered by Alice performing a local
>   measurement on system A. This remains true even if the systems A and B
>   are spatially separated. This is the foundation of the EPR paradox.
>
> The outcome of Alice's measurement is random. Alice cannot decide
>   which state to collapse the composite system into, and therefore
>   cannot transmit information to Bob by acting on her system. Causality
>   is thus preserved, in this particular scheme. For the general
>   argument, see no-communication theorem.

While it's discussed further [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem), the idea is that you can't use this instantaneous change to transfer information, because you can't control how it changes when you measure it.

Some believe (in the [many worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) of quantum mechanics) that the state itself does not instantaneously change, and that all of the possiblities still exist after measurement (that is, there's an alice that measures 0 and an alice that measures 1.) But by measuring the state alice is checking which of the alice's she is.

Comment: Where are you getting that it _instantaneously_ collapses? That isn't part of that quote.

Comment: If you read the section on wikipedia, I think that will be clear.  I'll add more in the answer to try to make the causality part more clear.

Comment: I am being a bit pedantic here but I think the use of the word “instantaneously” should be used very carefully in this context and might not even be applicable in certain cases. After all if Alice and Bob take their qubits to spacelike separated regions and then perform measurement, then whose measurement collapsed the wavefunction is debatable as there are frames in which Alice measures first while in another frame Bob measures the qubit first.

Comment: @ravjotsk My point exactly. The above passages don't actually say anything about the time at which collapse occurs for each person, and in fact such a comparison may be meaningless. In fact, I would argue that collapse for Alice _doesn't_ necessarily mean that Bob is in a pure state (after all, taking the partial inner product over Alice's qubit may still leave Bob in a superposition).

Comment: @probably_someone I agree that for the qubits to become entangled they were in a timelike region. However after they are entangled, I can take them to some distance away and agree beforehand to measure at such times that the event of measurement performed by Alice and that of Bob are 2 spacelike separated events, e.g., take them 600,000,000 m away from one another and perform the measurement within 1 s of each other

Comment: @ravjotsk You're correct, I'll remove my objection.

Comment: @RuanSunkel The spacetime interval between events (which is what determines whether the separation is spacelike, timelike, or lightlike) is not a frame-dependent quantity. So I don't see what your point is here.

Comment: @probably_someone, please ignore my frame comment. This discussion about frames, I realize now, is beyond my current understanding.

Comment: maybe open a new question about these details? seems like something it worth mentioning here, but it's a little unclear